# Print Preview of Hidden Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a code to print preview of a hidden worksheet but the print preview does not showing print option.

```
Sub PrintPreview()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Worksheets("Bill")
    .Range("J3").Value = ActiveCell.Value
    .Visible = xlSheetVisible
    .PrintPreview
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    .Visible = xlSheetHidden
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If you have Excel' s ribbon minimized, it will also be minimized in the print-preview screen, with a small menu. If that's the case press the `print-preview` menu item and the options will show up.

Comment: Excel ribbon is not minimized. This code is working without `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` but I want to take print preview without showing hidden worksheet.